# Gradle Jacoco - Could not find method jacocoTestReport()

Tags: java, android, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to generate a Jacoco test report in Gradle. When I try to sync my code, I will receive the following error:

> Error:(56, 0) Could not find method jacocoTestReport() for arguments [build_38ehqsoyd54r3n1gzrop303so$_run_closure4@10012308] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

My build.gradle file contains the following items:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    group = "Reporting"
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/coverage"
    }
}
```

When I look at the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) , I don't see anything which I'm doing wrong.

Gradle version: 3.3

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically I know two ways to achieve this.

**The first approach is the built-in android gradle plugin feature:**

```
android { 
    ... 
    buildTypes { 
       debug { 
          testCoverageEnabled = true 
       } 
       ... 
    } 
    ... 
}
```

This one will define gradle tasks, which can be executed. As far as I know this works fine with instrumentation tests. More information: [Code Coverage on Android](https://blog.gouline.net/code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-92ec90c9355e)

**The 2nd approach is to use this plugin:**

https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin

Setup is easy:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin:0.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.vanniktech.android.junit.jacoco'
```

And after project sync, you will have tasks like `jacocoTestReport<Flavor><BuildType>`

We use this to measure the code coverage of our unit tests running on the local machine.

Answer (score 13):

As stated in [documentation mentioned in your question](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html):

> If the Java plugin is also applied to your project, a new task named jacocoTestReport is created that depends on the test task.

what is pretty logical - measurement of coverage for Java code requires its compilation, execution of tests, etc.

So that indeed usage of your example of `build.gradle` causes failure, which disappears after addition of `apply plugin: 'java'`.

Comment: Hey, I already tried that. But I'm using this on Android, so I can't use `apply plugin: 'java'`. Sorry I forgot to mention that, I updated the tags.

Comment: @Guido I'm not developing for Android, but absence of `java` plugin looks weird. In any case I believe that you should report this incompatibility either to Gradle developers (because JaCoCo plugin is part of Gradle distribution), either to developers of plugins for Android.

Comment: This is already a known thing. You will also receive the following error when you try to use `apply plugin: 'java'` in an Android application: `Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.`