# How do I configure jacocoTestReport using init script in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I am trying to extend an existing build.gradle so that it updates jacocoTestReport so that XML reports are generated as they are now required by SonarQube

```
// allprojects {
// initscript {
rootProject {
  plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
  }
  //apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use `./gradlew -I jacoco.gradle check` but I am getting errors like

```
Could not find method plugins() for arguments [init_4poyb2mng02b0u77g0shf960p$_run_closure1$_closure2@1821f380] on root project 'template-ms' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the following answer in [Gradle Jacoco - Could not find method jacocoTestReport()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871349/gradle-jacoco-could-not-find-method-jacocotestreport) which indicated that the `java` plugin needs to be applied this is the result

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
    }
  }
}
```

and `./gradlew -I jacoco.gradle check jacocoTestReport` works correctly now

Also as a bonus, I was able to add a dependency

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
    }
  }
  check.dependsOn(jacocoTestReport)
}
```

So developers just need to do `./gradlew -I jacoco.gradle check`